# how to angular-ui-grid add column dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

in angular ui grid I am adding column definition dynamically as below.

in html I have

```
 <div id="ClientHT" data-ui-grid="gapAnalysisClientMatricsOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

in angularjs I am sending a request to database and accoarding to data I am getting columns lke below

```
      $scope.getData = function (RegionId, SubRegionId) {            
        datacontext.getDataFromUrl(Constants.Client.getGapAnalysisClientMatrics + "?regionIds=" + '2' + "&country=" + '' + "&subRegionId=" + '' + "&Ghc=" + '').then(data=> {                
            $scope.loading = false;
            if (data.Table2.length > 0) {                    
                $scope.CreateMatrics(data.Table2);

            }
            $scope.length = data.Table1.length;                
            $scope.gapAnalysisClientGridOptions.data = data.Table1;
            $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
            $scope.gridApi2.grid.refresh();
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }

        }, errorData => {
                toastr.error('Sorry, something went wrong while getting Gap Analysis client data', 'Error');
            });
    };


    $scope.CreateMatrics = function (dtMatrics) {            
        $scope.gapAnalysisClientMatricsOptions.data = dtMatrics;
        $scope.columns = [];
        var ArrColumns = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dtMatrics[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < ArrColumns.length; i++) {
            var colName = ArrColumns[i];
            $scope.columns.push({   
                field: ArrColumns[i]                    
                , displayName: ArrColumns[i]
                , headerTooltip: ArrColumns[i]
                , width: '150'
                , groupingShowAggregationMenu: false
                , enableGrouping: false
                , enableCellEdit: false 
                , cellTooltip: 'true'

            })

        }
        $scope.gridApi2.grid.refresh();

    }
```

in this celltooltip and cell template both is not working.please help me out if anybody got same issue.

Comment: which version of ui grid you are using? And Can you add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Alvaro my problem has reolved. I initialized the colDefs again after binding the data.Thanks